# Using AppleScript to Input large amounts of dates into Mac Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, applescript

I am new to AppleScript and I cannot seem to find any good sources to help me with my problem.
Given a file with dates and descriptions:

```
  September 5, 2013
  Event 1.

  September 8, 2013
  Event 2.

  etc.
```

I want to parse the file for the Date and event information, then create events in the Mac Calendar app that are at these days (with these descriptions ad the event titles). However, I am stuck with the following code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set Names to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Pick text file containing track names"))
    repeat with nextLine in Names
        set x to "Thursday, " & nextLine & " 12:00:00 AM"
        if nextLine starts with "Sept" then
            tell application "Calendar"
                tell calendar "My Calendar"
                    make new event with properties {description:"Event Description", summary:"Event Name", location:"Event Location", start date:date x, allday event:true}
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

The code does not work yet because it complains about the improper date format, and on top of that I have no idea how I could get the second line to be read with the date line.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the date parsing issue on my system by changing the external file format to:

```
5 September 2013
```

This could be a local system date format setting, as that is how mine is defined in the Language & Text - System Preference. Explore your settings first perhaps.

I've reworked your script a bit below to show you how to get at the event name by changing the loop to an index based one.

Also i've dropped the tell "Finder" block as it is not needed, you were not using any commands from the Finder in this case.

I also renamed some of your variables to be more legible (subjective), other tweaks are commented in the script.

```
set cal_data to the paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Pick text file containing track names"))
set c to the count of cal_data

repeat with i from 1 to c
    set currentLine to item i of cal_data
    if currentLine contains "September" then
        set dt to date (currentLine) -- Dropped the time as an all day event does not need this and the date parse will auto set it to 12:00am
        set ev_name to item (i + 1) of cal_data -- The next item in cal_data  should be the event name      
        tell application "Calendar" 
            tell calendar "My Calendar"
                make new event with properties {description:"Event Description", summary:ev_name, location:"Event Location", start date:dt, allday event:true}
            end tell
        end tell
    end if

end repeat
```

Hopefully this should get you onto the next steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did not know that you could use index-based loops in AppleScript. Do you recommend any resources that I can use to get better at AppleScript (I'm already familiar with Java and Python)? THANKS AGAIN

Comment: You're welcome. It's been a long time since i learnt so i can't recommend any current resources (except grab a book).
Otherwise Apples docs are pretty good. LangRef: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/AppleScriptLanguageGuide.pdf